# xcode 3.2.5 installed but no icon to open

Tags: xcode, macos

I installed vm ware mac os and also I installed xcode 3.2.5. its successfully installed but there is no icon to run or open the application. can any one say the issue to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

XCode should be located at `/Developer/Applications/XCode.app`. Drag it to your Dock.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i don't know where is developer folder?

Comment: Should be on your Macintosh HD. If it's not, you probably changed it to something else during installing or the installation didn't succeed.

Comment: i got a dislog box with the message like installation successfully

Comment: Then it has to be where you installed it. Default location is `/Developer/Applications/XCode.app`

Answer (score 0):

Should be located under /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app